# Current source or current mirror?

Tags: current, source, mirror

I've been told that using current sources in simulation programs may produce "too optimistic" results compared to using current mirrors. 
Could someone please elaborate? I'm still a bit confused about this topic.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is very specific, but I think what you're getting at is a more general concept.

In typical general-use simulators, "current sources" are modeled as ideal. An ideal current source will provide the exact amount of current requested regardless of external influences. It will adjust its voltage instantaneously as needed to continue to provide that exact current flow no matter what.

Realistic? Not at all. Any real current source will always be influenced by external forces. A sudden step change in load resistance, for example, may cause the current source to spike up or down. Or what if the load becomes open circuit? The realistic current source may attempt to raise its voltage until it fails catastrophically (or simply powers down if it's smart enough).

Using a current mirror as a realistic current source is one of many ways to model a more realistic current source. Current mirrors are very simply to build - just two transistors and a resistor - which is probably why this person suggested using them. But current mirrors exhibit properties that may not be adequate for your simulation. Sometimes an ideal current source will work just fine. Other times a more sophisticated model is necessary. As with all things electronics, it depends on your application.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been told that using current sources in simulation programs may
>   produce 'too optimistic' results compared to using current mirrors.

I wouldn't have thought so but, if you can find some quote on the internet, that would be a better approach for this question. We don't know the validity of the person who said this AND "simulation" could mean anything. Some sim tools (and models) might do a very good job of predicting the actual current produced whereas some others may be poor.

From my own experience of using micro-cap and having designed several current sources for strain gauge bridges, pressure bridges, RTCs and individual gauges I would say my simulation was accurate to within 0.1%.

Of course it may be argued that 0.1% is still inaccurate.

As for current mirrors I would say that these are likely to be more problematic than the general term "current source" AND therefore more likely to be flaky in simulation. I say this because the current sources that I use are all based around op-amp feedback systems and, at DC (up to 100s of kHz) the op-amp would ensure pretty tight control of the current generated.

Current mirrors tend not to use a high-gain, high-precision components like an op-amp to regulate current so, they are bound to be more flaky in both real life and simulation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about biasing in an analog IC, the use of ideal current sources will give you biasing that never runs out of headroom (the source will work even if the voltage across it reaches zero or goes negative) and infinite output impedance.

Real current sources need a bit of voltage to work and have finite output impedance (and less at higher frequencies).

Using a current mirror can model those effects, so your amplifier stops working at low supply voltage and has a more realistic lower gain than you'd expect with a perfect current source. Better current mirrors (for example Wilson mirror vs. a simple current mirror) may more closely approach the ideal current source. If you are modelling the other transistors accurately, then using ideal current sources in your circuits will tend to give better results than reality.

Answer (score 0):

Simple current mirrors (2 transistors) are prone to some undesired effects, such as not exactly matched pairs, dependency of the collector current on Vcc etc. Some can be mitigated by adding components, some cannot.